# Local copy of website(wget)

Tags: yii, wget

How i to get local copy of this docs - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/index ,
when i try to get with cmd - "wget -m -l1 http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/index" i recieved another page also(extensiton page, download page, and another pages from yii....com, but i want just this docs - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do You use all the flags? This command works for me

```
wget -m -l1 http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/index
```

Only be aware, that all the resources, like js, css and image files will still be stored on  http://www.yiiframework.com server. If You want to get full offline version, You will have to find different program, because this would require modifying resources source to local and saving all the extra stuff locally too